# Gijgo font icon not found in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, meteor

I have used [Gijgo npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gijgo) npm Date and time picker. after installing I have added this code one my js file.

```
import {gijgo} from 'gijgo';
import "gijgo/css/gijgo.min.css";
```

Now the problem is fonts are not founding but everything is working well. Below the screenshot.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you copied the gijgo fonts into your assets folder? make sure it's located one level up of the css file directory

The fonts can be found in here
[Gijgo Fonts](https://github.com/atatanasov/gijgo/tree/master/src/fonts)

Comment: Yes, When I installed with NPM it's automatically added in the folder.